# Custom description for Google search results

Tags: html, metadata, search-engine, google-search

When I search on Google, the description is always generated automatically based on meta tags. However I can influence the text shown when I add additional keywords, then the description will highlight these words from the said page. Here's a small example

[Google search result without keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28xTJ.png)

[Google search result with additional keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0qT2.png)

This shows that you can process the page without having to open it. Is there a way to increase the description length size or show only specific information based on its position on the page, or html tags?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to increase the description length size or show only specific information based on its position on the page, or html tags?

Short answer, no, but the content of the page [does matter](https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/crawling-indexing/) especially when no meta description is set.

For example, https://example.com/ doesn’t have a [meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) description so Google made up the description by parsing the content of the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it may be possible when you want to get a specific detail, you add the keywords that come right before ("This domain is for use in" will show you "examples in documents") but sometimes the text you're looking for isn't near anything precise which is the reason I'm looking for alternatives.